# Date Start + Hours

Tags: javascript, html

what is the problem with my code it doesn't compute the exact hours that i put

```
 <label for="start">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="start" onchange="calculateEndDate()">
    
    <label for="hours">Hours:</label>
    <select id="hours" onchange="calculateEndDate()">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    
    <label for="end">End Date:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="end" readonly>
    
    <script>
      function calculateEndDate() {
        const start = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);
        const hours = parseInt(document.getElementById("hours").value);
        const end = new Date(start.getTime() + hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        document.getElementById("end").value = end.toISOString().slice(0, -8);
      }
    </script>
```

[image]

can anyone help me with this problem thanks

I need to get this output:
date start: 03/08/2023 10:54 AM

Time Length 1hour

Answer
End Date: 03/08/2023 11:54 AM

Comment: Add your input and output.

Comment: You need to remove the timezone offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `toISOString()` takes the date object and alters the timezone to UTC. You get around that by adding or subtracting the current timezone's offset.

I also altered the `slice` to a `split` as your slice was removing too much information. The split will ensure the milliseconds and timezone are removed even if the browser does not include milliseconds for some reason (old browser?).

```html
 <label for="start">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="start" onchange="calculateEndDate()">
    
    <label for="hours">Hours:</label>
    <select id="hours" onchange="calculateEndDate()">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    
    <label for="end">End Date:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="end" readonly>
    
    <script>
      function calculateEndDate() {
        const start = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);
        const hours = parseInt(document.getElementById("hours").value);
        const end = new Date(start.getTime() + hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        // Add or subtract timezone offset so that
        // ISO UTC time string is actually local time.
        end.setMinutes(end.getMinutes() - end.getTimezoneOffset());
        document.getElementById("end").value = end.toISOString().split(/[\.Z]/)[0];
      }
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just remove the type (**type="datetime-local"**) from the input and add **toLocaleString()** to your end value

```html
<label for="start">Start Date:</label>
    <input type="datetime-local" id="start" onchange="calculateEndDate()">
    
    <label for="hours">Hours:</label>
    <select id="hours" onchange="calculateEndDate()">
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    
    <label for="end">End Date:</label>
    <input id="end" readonly>
    
    <script>
      function calculateEndDate() {
      debugger
        const start = new Date(document.getElementById("start").value);
        const hours = parseInt(document.getElementById("hours").value);
        const end = new Date(start.getTime() + hours * 60 * 60 * 1000);
        document.getElementById("end").value = end.toLocaleString();
      }
    </script>
```

Comment: it is possible that i use  
    <input type="datetime-local" id="end" readonly> for the output